# Debugging an elusive segfault

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault

What are the best ways to debug a c++ segfault when the following have been tried to no avail:

- isolating the code that appears to be causing the problem
- running under gdb
- running under valgrind with various tools and options
- commenting out segfaulting line to see if the segfault still occurs

Edit:

I found the source of my segfault. Imagine that the `#pragma pack( push, 1 )` line is buried deep within the included headers, and with no matching `#pragma push( pop )`, possibly due to `#if[n]def MACRO`s blindly being thrown in.

```
#pragma pack( push, 1 )

#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::set<int> a;
    a.insert( 1 );
    return 0;
}
```

This segfaults on my machine, and valgrind just complains about invalid reads. I don't know if gdb has any way of knowing this was caused by byte alignment.

Comment: What have you tried with gdb? With valgrind? I've yet to see a segfault that at least one, and oftentimes both, of those tools can't resolve.

Comment: for segfault `gdb` will be best tools....`valgrind` is use to check memory leas

Comment: with valgrind I've tried --tool=memcheck --track-origins=yes. All it reports is a `conditional jump or move depends on unitialised values`, but the uninitialzed value is an std::set created on the stack and passed by reference to a function. It wouldn't be unitialised under normal circumstances.

Comment: With gdb I've stepped into the function where it segfaults and noticed that variables within the set I've passed in by reference point to inaccessible memory. At this point I just need to figure out why the pointer inside the std::set is being corrupted.

Comment: I use gdb when faced with segfault.  I do not step, though.  Instead, I run the app.  When it segfaults, the debugger takes over, and I simply 'up' (climb-the-stack) to find the function it was in.  I do not stop in other-peoples-code (i.e. stl containers and such), but instead climb until in my code.  Then print some local's etc to find a cause.

Comment: If you're actually storing pointers in a set, i.e. `std::set<T*>`, maybe you should rethink that approach.

Comment: If the address is zero or small, that most likely means you have a null pointer / null reference problem. Chase the stack backwards from the point of the segfault. Sometimes you have to check for non-obvious things such `this` being null. (In the debugger, not in your code. Code should never contain `if (! this) { ... }`)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am storing integers in the set.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN The set is fine just before I call insert (`_M_left = 0x7fffe97fab78`). Just after, `_M_left = 0x7800000000000000`. `_M_left` should still be what it was one stack frame up, based on isolated tests I've done. How do I figure out what is modifying this value?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with your code, and you haven't provided any.  I probably can not help much.  Sometimes I would 'up' into my own code to review the operations happening there.  Often I go one or two steps higher, look at var's, then 'down' one (or twice) to understand how I got to this point Use 'p mySet' and 'p *this' and 'p *yourDataAttribute', really think about what your data attributes ought to be.  Hope this helps.  Is it hard to reproduce the seg fault in some minimal example?

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN What I meant was that member variables of the set change before the implementation even touches them. I just discovered an even crazier thing. If I create a set at the beginning of main and insert an element, my program crashes. Must be a static or global somewhere messing something up.

Comment: To catch an elusive segfault, you have to put on your ninja mask and lie in the shadows of the night for many hours, waiting for a sighting. If you are patient, your opportunity to strike will come.

Comment: @Brian try to produce a test case you can post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to debug a segfaulting program (let's hope you're using a version control system) is to rollback your commits until you reach a point where your program is no longer segfaulting. From that point, you know the next commit was the one that introduced the segfault.

In my case, the segfault was caused by a mismatched `#pragma pack( push, 1 )`, `#pragma pack( pop )`. This can cause errors that don't make any sense, like `std::set.insert` causing a segfault when called on a freshly allocated `std::set`.

Comment: Doesnt always work; e.g. if the segfault is based on an uninitialized variable, it could just be that the particular commit is nothing to do with the issue, but happens to change the value that the uninitialized variable was getting.

Comment: @MattMcNabb If that was the case, gdb/valgrind would probably be able to catch the segfault.